# How to manage Azure Blob size programmatically

Tags: azure

http://www.techxperiments.com/2015/10/14/block-blob-vs-page-blob-vs-append-blob/,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs
,After reading these article,I want to ask one question,that blob of all type are all fix size,files that we upload via app are vary in sizes too.
problem is that if we fix the size of blob ,and if file size may be large or small then this block?this will be in both cases not suitable,e.g if block size large and file size small ,then this extra space is waste of money?and if file size greater than blob size then it will be loss of data?what will be the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the documents. When it comes to blobs, the size of a blob is not fixed. The maximum size of a blob is.

What that means is that you can't store anything bigger than the maximum size allowed for a blob (e.g. 1TB for Page Blob). Anything smaller than that (including 0 byte blob) can be stored and you will be charged for the amount of data stored.

Only exception to this rule is when you create a `Page Blob` in a `Premium` storage account. There you will be charged tiered pricing. So for example, in a `Premium` storage account even if you create a 1GB page blob you will be charged for 128 GB of storage. In all other storage accounts, you will be charged for the actual storage space used by the blob.

Comment: correct me if I wrong please, its mean if I upload a file with size 49kb,and blob size that I have configured is 64 kb, then charges will be apply on base of 49kb or 64kb? What I got from your words that it will be apply on 49kb?am I right?

Comment: So if you upload 49KB blob, you will get charged for 49KB of storage. Can you please share how you're configuring the size of a blob to be 64KB?

Comment: that was just for explanation,basically  each time when I upload a file ,it creates blockblob,

Comment: I think you're getting confused with 64MB limit for a blob. Basically what this limit is that any blob less than 64MB in size can be uploaded without splitting in smaller chunks (called blocks). Anything bigger than 64MB must be split in chunks (where max size of a chunk is 4MB) and these chunks must be uploaded separately. Of course you can split any sized blob in smaller chunks and the chunk size can be as small as 1 byte. Hope this clarifies your confusion.

Comment: A BunDla Of ThAnks